# Oracle SQL: Enumerate rows by group and child entries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
Question_Id   Question_text   Question_Answer_id     Date  
------------  --------------  ------------------     --------
1             First Question                         1-1-2021
2             First Answer    1                      2-1-2021
3             Second Answer   1                      3-1-2021
4             Random Question                        4-1-2021
5             Random Answer   4                      5-1-2021
6             Another Answer  4                      6-1-2021
```

And I need to display something like the following SELECT

```
Question_Id   Question_text   Question_Answer_id     Date       Order
------------  --------------  ------------------     --------   --------
1             First Question                         1-1-2021   001
2             First Answer    1                      2-1-2021   001.001
3             Second Answer   1                      3-1-2021   001.002
4             Random Question                        4-1-2021   002
5             Random Answer   4                      5-1-2021   002.001
6             Another Answer  4                      6-1-2021   002.002
```

I need to display a new order with a SELECT, this Order column based on the entries that have an answer ID. I tried to use a function Row_number() but I can't get it right.

Order is not another table

How can I do this type of enumeration?

Comment: Please add full table and sample data for your order table. We have no idea how your tables look like

Comment: how are those values in the "Order" question derived ?

Comment: The "Order" is not another table, I'm trying to do something like "SELECT *, row_number FROM table"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your hierarchy is only two deep (which makes sense for questions/answers), you can use window functions.  In particular, you can use `dense_rank()` to assign a number to the questions and then `dense_rank()` again for the answers within each question.  The rest is just formatting the final string:

```
select t.*,
       (lpad(dense_rank() over (order by coalesce(t.Question_Answer_id, t.question_id)), 3, '0') ||
        (case when t.Question_Answer_id is not null
              then '.' || lpad(dense_rank() over (partition by t.Question_Answer_id order by t.question_id), 3, '0')
         end))
from t
order by question_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81645f36c46095bb7ef4d846bfce2bd7) is a db<>fiddle.